# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in map

Tags: java, arrays, exception, program-entry-point, bounds

I have the next problem to compile using NetBeans and console in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

My code is (in the line of error):

```
Object maxFreK = map.keySet().toArray()[0];
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 0` means that your **array doesn't contain any elements.**
It is an empty array.

You can use somenthing like this:

```
Object maxFreK=null; 
if (!map.isEmpty()){
  maxFreK = map.keySet().toArray()[0];
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was the problem, now I try to find how I can put elements in this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This exception shows that your map is empty and your are accessing the first key which is not present. Before accessing any element from the keyset, check if the array/keyset contains elements

for e.g.

```
Object [] objArr = map.keySet().toArray();
if(objArr.length>0){
   Object maxFreK = objArr [0];
}
```